# Exibir apenas horas, minutos e segundos em um gráfico cuja entrada está em unix time

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib

Seja o código Python que gera um gráfico em barras:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = []
y = []
with open("dados.csv") as f:
    for l in f:
        X,Y = l.split(",") #separador eh a virgula
        x.append(float(X))
        y.append(float (Y))

x1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)) for d in x]
y_pos = [idx for idx, i in enumerate(y)]

plt.figure(figsize=(17,9))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter(' %H:%M:%S'))

plt.bar(y_pos, y, align='edge', color="blue", alpha=0.5, width=0.5) # <--- EDICAO PRINCIPAL
plt.title("Valores")
plt.ylabel("Numeros")
plt.xlabel('Tempo')
plt.xticks(y_pos, x1, size='small',rotation=35, ha="right")
plt.yticks(y)
plt.ylim(ymax=sorted(y)[-1]+1) # valor maximo do eixo y
#plt.ylim(ymin=sorted(y)[0]-1) # valor minimo do eixo y

plt.show()
```

O arquivo dados.csv, onde a primeira coluna está em unix time :

```
1504439700,37438
1504439880,33072
1504439940,576
1504440000,62
1504440060,17731
1504440120,42874
1504440300,59323
1504440360,6601
1504440420,14495
1504440480,8494
1504440540,56293
1504440660,49168
1504440720,11993
1504440780,15700
1504440840,11993
1504440900,7009
```

O gráfico gerado ficou assim:

[image: grafico]

Gostaria que fosse exibida apenas a hora, minuto e segundo, omitindo o dia, o mês e o ano. É possível?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[TL;DR]](https://anaconda.org/sidon/pandas-plot-bar1/notebook)

Abaixo vai um exemplo com a utilização do pandas, baseado nele voce pode, facilmente, adaptar o seu codigo, não é mandatorio a utilização do pandas, após o exemplo faço uma sugestão para adapatr seu codigo:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = '''time,data
1504439700,37438
1504439880,33072
1504439940,576
1504440000,62
1504440060,17731
1504440120,42874
1504440300,59323
1504440360,6601
1504440420,14495
1504440480,8494
1504440540,56293
1504440660,49168
1504440720,11993
1504440780,15700
1504440840,11993
1504440900,7009'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), parse_dates=True)
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.time

df.plot.bar(x=df.time)
```

Resultado:

[image: Gráfico de barras com o pandas]

Para adaptar seu código tente mudar a linha onde vc atribui os valores à variável `x1` para que ela receba apenas os 8 últimos caracteres de timestamp. Deixo uma sugestão abaixo, mas ja adianto que, como não testei, pode ser que tenha algum erro e não funcione, a ideia é apenas apontar um caminho:

```
x1 = [str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)))[-8:] for d in x]
```

[Baixe ou veja o codigo renderizado em um jupyter notebook.](https://anaconda.org/sidon/pandas-plot-bar1/notebook)

Comment: Obrigado! Vou testar e retorno aqui!

Comment: tentei modificar o código com a sua sugestão (x1 = [str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d))[-8:]) for d in x]) e o erro
foi:

TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable

Alguma ideia?
Desde já agradeço a sua atenção!

Comment: Editei a restposta e fiz uma pequena alteração, veja se funciona agora.

Comment: obrigado. Me refiro a correção do meu código. Não consigo fazer funcionar com "x1 = [str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)))[-8:] for d in x]"

Comment: seu código é muito bom. Apenas gostaria de saber como modificar o meu, se possível!

Comment: desculpe! Funcionou agora. É que não consegui ver a diferença! Poderia explicar?

Comment: Repare que eu apenas converti o que vc ja tinha pensado o `datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)` para string com a função str `str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)))` e então pego os 8 ultimos caracteres, que é o horário, acontece que eu havia colocado o parenteses (para a conversão para str) no lugar errado, estava assim:  `(x1 = [str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d))[-8:])`, veja q na versão final eu desloco o parenteses final 6 caracteres à esquerda.